# How to save the text entered in dynamic created edittext after orientation changes

Tags: android

I have 2 edittext these are dynamically created. when entered some text and change orientation edittext data losing.
because onSaveInstanceState calling 2 times. while debugging first time I am getting values. but 2nd time the values are null.

Comment: lowvalue=new EditText(getActivity());       highvalue=new EditText(getActivity());

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared-preferences to save the data at the first time and get the data after changing the orientation:

I hope this will help you. Use Like this:

```
public static void setSharedPrefStringData(Context context, String key,
        String value) {
    SharedPreferences appInstallInfoSharedPref = context
            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME,
                    context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    Editor appInstallInfoEditor = appInstallInfoSharedPref.edit();
    appInstallInfoEditor.putString(key, value);
    appInstallInfoEditor.commit();
}

public static String getSharedPrefStringData(Context context, String key) {

    SharedPreferences userAcountPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

    return userAcountPreference.getString(key, "");

}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

you can override `onConfigurationChanged` please visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

you can do this as follows

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration currentConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(currentConfig);

        //yours implementation with respect to edittext
    }
```

Please try to work with `onConfigurationChanged` method and override in the given way !!
suppose you have a main activity as MainActivity 
and registered to manifest as follows

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity " >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

As a first step you can add the attribute `android:configChanges` inside the activity tag.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity "
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Next step is about necessary to implement the logic for handling this layout change manually at yours activity code. For this you need to override the method 
onConfigurationChanged() inside MainActivity .

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration currentConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(currentConfig);

    //yours implementation with respect to edittext
}
```

Comment: two edit texts are in fragments.

Comment: than handle in fragment-avtivity, it depends on yours code writing!!